# Passing a dictionary to Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have an Ajax call on a `on('click',)` event. The data passed from my HTML is `value= '{{y.id }} {{ y.id }}'`.
Ajax passes it to my `views.py` in python server side as a `str` .

Is there a way to get it straight as a list or dictionary? Or do I have to extract it and convert it in my `views.py`?

My html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}            
                <form class="add_btn" method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
                <button class='added btn' value='{{x.id }}{{ y.id }}' ><i class=' fas fa-save'></i></button>              
{% endif %}
```

My Ajax:

```
$(".added").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    var prefered = $(this).val();      
    var url = '/finder/add/';   
    $.ajax({        
        url: url,        
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            'prefered': prefered,            
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data['success']) 
            console.log(prefered);        
        }
    }); 
});
```

My views.py

```
def add(request):
    data = {'success': False} 
    if request.method=='POST':
        prefered = request.POST.get('prefered')
        print (prefered)
        print (type(prefered))
        user = request.user
        print (user)         
        data['success'] = True
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, your server side running python will receive the AJAX data in a stringified JSON format, and the parsing is all left to the application layer.

**Which means you will have to do the parsing inside your `views.py` in your case**. But, with the help of packages like `json` or `simplejson` it should be fairly easy.

Note that the parsing might take place inside a middleware layer in some situations, thus making it easier for the application (`views.py` for example), but setting up a middleware layer is an overhead that you typically want to avoid for small projects.